# How to get an API response

Tags: php, api, curl

I have this response:

```
{
    "Contratos": [
        {
            "IdCUPS": 0,
            "CodigoCUPS": "",
            "IdContrato": 0,
            "CodigoContrato": null,
            "IdCliente": 0,
            "IdDocumento": null,
            "IdEmpresa": null,
            "Incidencias": [
                {
                    "Propiedad": "CodigoCUPS",
                    "Code": 0,
                    "CodeAlfa": "",
                    "Mensaje": "El cups ya esta asignado a contratos activos",
                    "IsAdvertencia": false,
                    "IsError": true,
                    "IsExcepcion": false,
                    "ExceptionTimestamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "ExceptionMessage": "",
                    "ExceptionStackTrace": "",
                    "InnerException": "",
                    "ImageSource": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I access to the 'Mensaje' option? 
I have this code where i make curl_init and its options:

```
$ch = curl_init($url.$contratoPotencial);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I tried with this code:

```
echo "<br><br> Mensaje: ";
echo "<br>".$response->Contratos->Incidencias->Mensaje;
```

But it not works!

Comment: Why would that code have any hope of working? Read [the manual on how arrays work](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Also note `Incidencias` is a regular array so you'll need to reference element 0, not just skip over that as if it's not there.

Comment: Try stepping through it and see what you're actually working with, `var_dump($response)` etc. You have a mix of objects and arrays and the syntax for using these vary (you're trying to use every sub item as an object)

Comment: try `$data = json_decode($response);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mix of array and object in json: try below solution:

```
$response = '{
    "Contratos": [
        {
            "IdCUPS": 0,
            "CodigoCUPS": "",
            "IdContrato": 0,
            "CodigoContrato": null,
            "IdCliente": 0,
            "IdDocumento": null,
            "IdEmpresa": null,
            "Incidencias": [
                {
                    "Propiedad": "CodigoCUPS",
                    "Code": 0,
                    "CodeAlfa": "",
                    "Mensaje": "El cups ya esta asignado a contratos activos",
                    "IsAdvertencia": false,
                    "IsError": true,
                    "IsExcepcion": false,
                    "ExceptionTimestamp": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "ExceptionMessage": "",
                    "ExceptionStackTrace": "",
                    "InnerException": "",
                    "ImageSource": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}';

$responseData = json_decode($response);
echo "<br><br> Mensaje: ";
echo "<br>".$responseData->Contratos[0]->Incidencias[0]->Mensaje;
```

**Output**

```
Mensaje: 
El cups ya esta asignado a contratos activos
```

**OR**

Encode complete json into array as below:

```
$responseData = json_decode($response, true);
echo "<br><br> Mensaje: ";
echo "<br>".$responseData['Contratos'][0]['Incidencias'][0]['Mensaje'];
```

In both case you will get desired output

Answer (score 2):

do a **json_decode** like below,

```
$respData = json_decode($response, true);
```

and then print

```
echo $respData['Contratos']['Incidencias']['Mensaje'];
```